# .NET CORE API: Is it possible to conditionally validate a model depending on the http verb used to submit it?

Tags: fluentvalidation

I'm very new to the FluentValidation and I'd like to validate my model in different ways depending on which verb was used to submit it.

Given a very simple class, I'd like to ignore the `ID` property on a `POST` but ensure it's been provided on a `PUT`. Is this something the FluentValidation can do?

```cpp
 public class CategoryModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

I'm guessing I have to get the `HttpContext` over to the validators so I can determine the http method used, but I don't want to re-invent the wheel if there's already a built-in way.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

I think I've come up with a solution by passing the context to my validator. However, if something looks wrong or out of place, please let me know.

```cpp
public class CategoryModel
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }


public class CategoryModelValidator : AbstractValidator<CategoryModel>
    {
        public CategoryModelValidator(IHttpContextAccessor context)
        {
            if (context.HttpContext.Request.Method == HttpMethods.Post)
                RuleFor(x => x.ID).Empty();

            if (context.HttpContext.Request.Method == HttpMethods.Put)
                RuleFor(x => x.ID).NotEmpty();

            RuleFor(x => x.Name).Length(1, 30);
        }
    }
```

Passing the context was easier than I thought. All I had to do was register it in my `ConfigureServices` method with `services.AddHttpContextAccessor()` and DI takes care of the rest.

To be honest, this is a pretty handy validation tool